# Derivative inside an integral

Tags: measure-theory, integration, optimization

Assume that I have an integral 
$$
I=\int_\Omega f(\omega)g(\omega)d\omega,
$$
where $\Omega$ is a measure space and $\omega\in \Omega$. 
What is 
$$
\frac{\partial I}{\partial f(\omega)}?
$$
i.e. I want to study the effect of a change in $f$ on $I$, is this possible?

The motivation of this question comes from an economic model of preference for varieties by Dixit and Stiglitz:
In the Dixit-Stiglitz model, the representative consumer's utility function is
$$
U=\left(\int_0^n q(\omega)^\rho d\omega\right)^{\frac{1}{\rho}}, 0<\rho<1,
$$
where $q(\omega)$ is the consumption of variety $\omega$, $n$ is the mass of varieties available to the consumer. The consumer's budget constrain is
$$
\int_0^n p(w)q(\omega) d\omega=I
$$
The consumer wants to maximize $U$ w.r.t $q$, the consumption. In a paper I found the following way of dealing with this problem:

Let the Lagrangian be 
$$
L=U^\rho-\lambda(\int_0^n p(w)q(\omega) d\omega-I)
$$ 
The first order condition is
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q(\omega)}=\rho q(\omega)^{\rho-1}-\lambda  p(\omega)=0.
$$
I don't know how to get this first order condition. In the paper the author explains as:
[image]

But I don't see the justification for this operation from my math knowledge. After some abstraction, I think my question can be summarized by the derivative inside an integral problem as stated at the beginning of this post.

Comment: What is $A$ and $\omega$. As it stands, $I$ is just a constant..

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315929/first-order-condtion-of-the-dixit-stiglitz-model Please see my another question for the motivation of this question.

Comment: @TongZhang: Leaving the link between the two questions is fine, but you should include all relevant information in each post.  In other words, ask as detailed a question as you would if you thought no one had seen your previous questions.  You can certainly cite your motivation, however.

Comment: @JavaMan Thanks for you advice. I deleted the old post and combined them into this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the function $I(f) = \int f(\omega) \, g(\omega) \, \mathrm{d}\omega$. Then, the directional derivative $I'(f)\,h = \int h(\omega) \, g(\omega) \, \mathrm{d}\omega$. Hence, the partial derivative of $I$ w.r.t. $f$ can be interpreted as the function $g$.

Comment: I don't get the directional derivative part. Why can the directional derivative of $I$ along $h$ be represented as $\int h(\omega)g(\omega)d\omega$?

Comment: Just use the definition of the directional derivative:
$$I'(f) \, h = \lim_{t \searrow 0} (I(f+t\,h)-I(f))/t$$.

Comment: This definition works also for the infinite dimensional case?